# is node.js' console.log asynchronous?

Tags: asynchronous, console, node.js

Are `console.log/debug/warn/error` in node.js asynchrounous? I mean will javascript code execution halt till the stuff is printed on screen or will it print at a later stage?

Also, I am interested in knowing if it is possible for a console.log to NOT display anything if the statement immediately after it crashes node.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

**Update:** Starting with Node 0.6 this post is obsolete, since stdout is *synchronous* now.

Well let's see what `console.log` actually does.

First of all it's part of the [console module](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/console.js#L34):

```
exports.log = function() {
  process.stdout.write(format.apply(this, arguments) + '\n');
};
```

So it simply does some formatting and writes to `process.stdout`, nothing asynchronous so far.

`process.stdout` is a getter [defined on startup](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/master/src/node.js#L503) which is lazily initialized, I've added some comments to explain things:

```
.... code here...
process.__defineGetter__('stdout', function() {
  if (stdout) return stdout;                            // only initialize it once 

  /// many requires here ...

  if (binding.isatty(fd)) {                             // a terminal? great!
    stdout = new tty.WriteStream(fd);
  } else if (binding.isStdoutBlocking()) {              // a file?
    stdout = new fs.WriteStream(null, {fd: fd});
  } else {
    stdout = new net.Stream(fd);                        // a stream? 
                                                        // For example: node foo.js > out.txt
    stdout.readable = false;
  }

  return stdout;
});
```

In case of a TTY and UNIX we end up [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/master/lib/tty.js#L90), this thing inherits from socket. So all that node bascially does is to push the data on to the socket, then the terminal takes care of the rest.

**Let's test it!**

```
var data = '111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111';
for(var i = 0, l = 12; i < l; i++) {
    data += data; // warning! gets very large, very quick
}

var start = Date.now();
console.log(data);
console.log('wrote %d bytes in %dms', data.length, Date.now() - start);
```

**Result**

```
....a lot of ones....1111111111111111
wrote 208896 bytes in 17ms

real    0m0.969s
user    0m0.068s
sys  0m0.012s
```

The terminal needs around 1 seconds to print out the sockets content, but node only needs 17 milliseconds to push the data to the terminal.

The same goes for the stream case, and also the file case gets handle [asynchronous](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L1563).

So **yes** Node.js holds true to its non-blocking promises.

Comment: Update: stdout in node.js is now synchronous: http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/8c85c2dae1a1f585

Comment: I think this is obsolete now : https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3524#issuecomment-151097761

Comment: @IvoWetzel I'm going to have to downvote this now as it is obsolete.

Comment: I know this is obsolete and everything, but you say “nothing asynchronous so far” immediately after `process.stdout.write()` where `write()` is by definition asynchronous…

Comment: What about on Windows?

Answer (score 29):

console.warn() and console.error() are blocking.  They do not return until the underlying system calls have succeeded.

Yes, it is possible for a program to exit before everything written to stdout has been flushed.  process.exit() will terminate node immediately, even if there are still queued writes to stdout.  You should use console.warn to avoid this behavior.

Comment: This is not true for Node 0.10.25 in Windows. `console.warn()` and `console.error()` have the same non-blocking behaviour of `console.log()`. There's even a [package to solve the problem in Windows](https://www.npmjs.org/package/exit).

Answer (score 13):

My Conclusion , after reading Node.js 10.* docs (Attached below). is that you can use console.log for logging , **console.log** is synchronous and implemented in low level c . 
Although console.log is synchronic, it wont cause a performance issue only if you are not logging huge amount of data.

(The command line example  below demonstrate, console.log **async** and console.error is **sync**)

Based on [Node.js Doc's](http://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data)

> The console functions are synchronous when the destination is a terminal or a file (to avoid lost  messages in case of premature exit) and asynchronous when it's a pipe (to avoid blocking for long  periods of time).
>
> That is, in the following example, stdout is non-blocking while stderr is blocking:

`$ node script.js 2> error.log | tee info.log`

> In daily use, the blocking/non-blocking dichotomy is not something you should worry about unless you >  log huge amounts of data.

Hope it helps

Comment: What is a "huge amount of data"? Is it defined by number of calls to console.log or the total amount being written? What is a huge 1KB/ms, 1MB/ms, 1GB/ms?

Comment: such things are discovered by experimentations :) @MattG

Answer (score 3):

Console.log is asynchronous in windows while it is synchronous in linux/mac. To make console.log synchronous in windows write this line at the start of your 
code probably in index.js file. Any console.log after this statement will be considered as synchronous by interpreter.

```
if (process.stdout._handle) process.stdout._handle.setBlocking(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this for synchrounous logging:

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.writeSync(1, 'Sync logging\n')
```