# "Caching" identical MySQL results for all users

Tags: php, mysql, caching, apc

I'm hoping to develop a LAMP application that will centre around a small table, probably less than 100 rows, maybe 5 fields per row. This table will need to have the data stored within accessed rapidly, maybe up to once a second per user (though this is the 'ideal', in practice, this could probably drop slightly). There will be a number of updates made to this table, but SELECTs will far outstrip UPDATES.

Available hardware isn't massively powerful (it'll be launched on a VPS with perhaps 512mb RAM) and it needs to be scalable - there may only be 10 concurrent users at launch, but this could raise to the thousands (and, as we all hope with these things, maybe 10,000s, but this level there will be more powerful hardware available).

As such I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction for a starting point - all the data retrieved will be the same for all users, so I'm trying to investigate if there is anyway of sharing this data across all users, rather than performing 10,000 identical selects a second. Soooo:

1) Would the mysql_query_cache cache these results and allow access to the data, WITHOUT requiring a re-select for each user? 
2) (Apologies for how broad this question is, I'd appreciate even the briefest of reponses greatly!) I've been looking into the APC cache as we already use this for an opcode cache - is there a method of caching the data in the APC cache, and just doing one MYSQL select per second to update this cache - and then just accessing the APC for each user? Or perhaps an alternative cache?

Failing all of this, I may look into having a seperate script which handles the queries and outputs the data, and somehow just piping this one script's data to all users. This isn't a fully formed thought and I'm not sure of the implementation, but perhaps a combo of AJAX to pull the outputted data from... "Somewhere"... :)

Once again, apologies for the breadth of these question - a couple of brief pointers from anyone would be very, very greatly appreciated.
Thanks again in advance

Comment: Don't use MySQL cache, but Memcached

Comment: @RomanNewaza - Thanks Roman, I'll look into Memcache :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're doing something like an AJAX chat which polls the server constantly, you may want to look at [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) instead, which keeps an open connection between server and browser. This way, you can have changes pushed to the user when they happen and you won't need to do all that redundant checking once per second. This can scale very well to thousands of users and is written in javascript on the server-side, so not too difficult.

Comment: I just started to learn about node.js and mongodb but not sure how the code/script for the front end looks like?

Comment: @Matt Gibson - Thanks for this, I've never looked into node.js before, but from the initial glance it looks pretty much like what I need (we're looking at something very similar to an AJAX chat) - many thanks

Comment: @Matt Gibson: What I mean is how the front end code interacts with server side javascript code?Can you give some example because I am new to node and mongodb?

Comment: @HieuVanMach Try this http://www.martinsikora.com/nodejs-and-websocket-simple-chat-tutorial

Comment: Thanks Matt Gibson.Nice article and it is what I am looking for.I got another question that I want to build a real time stat display web application quite similar to the article which displays website stats collecting from users visiting,site behaviors and storing in mongodb. Can I start from the article you sent to me?

Comment: @HieuVanMach yes, that should provide a pretty good starting point. Instead of sending out chat messages as they come in, you would need some sort of trigger on mongodb that would call a node.js function when data was updated, so that it could be sent out to the right clients.

Comment: @MattGibson: Thanks so much. Now I got some ready code and your guide so I can start building it now. Then probably git it for someone to re-use....

Comment: @MattGibson:I need your help again as I just wonder where the messages store like writing to logs in the server because I see console.log()...

Comment: @HieuVanMach have a look at the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127532/is-node-js-console-log-asynchronous

Comment: @MattGibson: Sorry for slow understanding. I still do not get it because the messages must be stored somewhere in this case websocket does the job,does not it?Because I have test on 2 browsers Firefox and Chrome, it displays every messages on 2 browsers and I found it very cool when the message just comes and popup...There is not ajax call every call to request new message instead websocket does the job which is one of the best thing I have ever seen on front end stuffs....

Comment: @MattGibson: I saw it Matt in the chat-server.js there is var history = new Array(); which I think this array holds all messages.Now I understand it.Thank you so much for sending me this article.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using the MySQL cache is that the entire table cache gets invalidated on any write to that table. You're better off using a caching solution like memcached or APC if you're trying to control that behavior more precisely. And yes, APC would be able to cache that information.

One other thing to keep in mind is that you need to know when to *invalidate* the cache as well, so you don't have stale data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apc,xcache or memcache for database query caching or you can use vanish or squid for gateway caching...