# What is the difference between util.error and console.error in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

What exactly is the difference between the `util.error([...])` and `console.error([...])`?

In both of the methods it prints to stderr.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Documentation

### [util.error](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_error)

> Same as util.debug() except this will output all arguments immediately to stderr.

#### [util.debug](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_debug_string)

> A synchronous output function. Will block the process and output string immediately to stderr.

### [console.error](http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console_error_data)

> Same as console.log but prints to stderr.

#### [console.log](http://nodejs.org/api/stdio.html#stdio_console_log_data)

> Prints to stdout with newline. This function can take multiple arguments in a printf()-like way. Example:
>
> ```
> console.log('count: %d', count);
> ```
>
> If formatting elements are not found in the first string then util.inspect is used on each argument. See [util.format()](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format) for more information.

## Conclusion

According to [is node.js' console.log asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127532/is-node-js-console-log-asynchronous) the console.log is asynchronous(node>=0.6), therefore also console.error. But util.error will block the process and output to stderr, according to the documentation above.

Comment: Very nicely answered.. I was having same doubts but had no supportive docs. Thanks for well explained answer..

Answer (score 10):

Just in case anyone comes across this question again, `util.error` is **DEPRECATED** so stick to `console.error`!

Comment: Just verified, with Node 5+ `util.error` is deprecated