# Node.js console.log vs console.info

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, console

What is the benefit of using `console.log` vs `console.info`?
Or any of the other console commands for that matter?

```
console.info("info");
console.error("error");
console.warn("warn");
```

vs

```
console.log("log");
```

I thought it might change the color of the output or concatenate some sort of label, but they seem to all do the same thing. And according to the documentation here:

https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_info_data

they seem to all do the same as `console.log`

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437428/what-is-the-difference-between-util-error-and-console-error-in-node-js

Comment: Some tips:

You can use colors to have a better view of:
console.log('%c Sample Text', 'color:green;');

Or add some VAR in the text using:
console.log(\`Sample ${variable}\`, 'color:green;');

Comment: I definitely wrap all my logging functionality in an in house adapter or some logging library but I think the difference between `log` and `info` is an interesting idealogical question. I personally think `debug` is (naturally) for debugging, `log` is for extra context that may be verbose (contrary to Chrome's devtools logging levels filter) and `info` is for logging important context changes like a routing change in a SPA or sign-in/out changes. Honestly still an up-to-you / YMMV situation imo ‾\\_(ツ)_/‾

Answer (score 123, accepted):

According to [the documentation that you linked to](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_info_data), `console.error` and `console.warn` output to `stderr`.  The others output to `stdout`.

If you are doing piping or redirection from `node.js` the difference is important.

There is a lot of JavaScript written to run in both the browser and `Node.js`.  Having node implement the full console allows for greater code cross-compatibility.

In most browsers, not only do these log in different colors, but you can also filter to see specific messages.

```js
console.debug("debug"); // Likely hidden by default
console.info("info");
console.error("error");
console.warn("warn");
console.log("log");
```

Comment: Thank you! It was the browser where it shows up differently. I was looking in terminal for the color changes.

Comment: In `node` (`8.11.4`) and Chrome 67, there's also `console.debug` (and quite likely earlier versions as well). `debug` ranks below `log`.

Answer (score 88):

While `console.log` and `console.info` might seem the same, with only mere coloring differences (in most browsers), you can take advantage of having these differently named functions.

For example, you can configure a linter like eslint to produce a warning message whenever `console.log` is used but no warnings for `console.info`. Now you can use `console.log` for temporary development/debug logging and `console.info` for information that end users might need. The linter warnings will remind or even force you to removed the temporary `console.log` calls before commits code or publishing release builds.

Comment: I dont know why I found this answer more appropriate then all others, nice one @Figidon .

Comment: I concurr. Great solution to use with eslint for dev and production mode. You shall not pass console.log! (staff and sword in hand)

Comment: Also monitoring tools, such as DataDog, automatically place logs produced by `console.info`, `console.error`, and `console.warn` into the categories "Info", "Error", and "Warn" respectively which allows for further log filtering.

Answer (score 32):

According to the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html) it's pretty clear.

> console.info([data], [...])#
> Same as console.log.
>
> console.error([data], [...])#
> Same as console.log but prints to stderr.
>
> console.warn([data], [...])#
> Same as console.error.

This means there is no benefit or downside. `info` == `log`, and `warn` == `error`. Unless you want to print to `stderr`, `info` and or `log` will work.

Comment: I mean, log vs info may be ambiguous but I'm pretty sure the concept of warnings vs errors is a thing in software development. Chrome dev console will log a stack trace for both warn and error but they're colored differently. Similar with running tests in Jest with Node

Answer (score 28):

Visually, No difference actually among `console.log` , `console.info` , `console.warn` , as well as `console.error` regarding the **server side(terminal)**.

However, there are [lightweight modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/console-info) that add **blue, orange and red colors**  for `console.info` , `console.warn` , as well as `console.error` respectively . By that, console API behaves like client-side.

```
 npm i console-info console-warn console-error --save-dev;
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

One more detail in addition to the accepted answer: In Chrome and FireFox, `console.info` log lines are prefixed with a little **i** icon while `console.log` lines are not. `warn` and `error` lines are prefixed with a little triangle and **x**, respectively.

Comment: As observed elsewhere: Firefox 78: prints ⓘ (i in circle) before log.info output. Chrome 84: doesn't

Comment: Is it possible that the behavior for console.info was changed? I don't see any "i icon" in Chrome...

Answer (score 9):

**stdin**
A readable stream for reading input from the user.

**stdout**
A writable stream, either synchronously or asynchronously.

**stderr**
A blocking synchronous writable stream intended for error messages.

The stdout or **non-blocking** functions are: console.log, console.info, util.puts, util.print and Stderr.

The **blocking functons** are: console.warn, console.error, util.debug and process.stdin (a readable stream for getting user input).

Answer (score 6):

I have seen where `console.log` is for temporarily logging of state information for debugging.

`console.info` is a more permanent thing - such as saying what port something is running on, and something you wouldn't cut out after you are done debugging.

This makes it easy to clean up your code for committing it. You can even have your linter have a rule to prevent console.log from being committed.

Answer (score 5):

It has been established that log and info are basically the same thing, but I'm not sure that completely answers the question:

> What is the benefit of using console.log vs console.info?

One benefit, apart from what has already been mentioned, is you can use each for a different purpose. For example, you might use console.log just for quick debugging and spitting things out to the console, while you might use console.info for permanent messages you want to output to the console in your code, such as information on the current app status. Then when you have a situation where a random object is printed in your console and you realize you've left a log statement in there somewhere by accident, you can do a global search for 'console.log' and delete every instance and have confidence you didn't delete anything important that you meant to leave in there.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference for React devs.  It comes from an issue in the react devtool extension and at least affects Create-React-App users, not sure if it's all web pack.

Issue is mentioned here:
[react devtools console.log() from react_devtools_backend.js:4049](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69071151/react-devtools-console-log-from-react-devtools-backend-js4049)

but the jist is:
console.log will always report its source as

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4049
```

wheres console.info will have the actual filename and line number you're logging from.

Comment: Useful, even 6 years later, to know this.

Answer (score 2):

**The different logging levels let you manage the noise level in your console:**  In both the Firefox (I'm using 78 right now) and Chrome (84) devtools, the js console lets you choose what "debug level" of output you want to see.  FF lets you toggle the visibility of `console.error`, `.warn`, `.log`, `.info`, and `.debug` messages by clicking individual buttons for each (that show you how many were suppressed, when "off"), whereas Chrome has a dropdown with checkmarks next to the items (`.info` and `.log` are controlled by the "Info" one, and `.debug` by "Verbose").  The Chrome dropdown label ("All levels" or whatever you set) turns red if output was suppressed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with debugging real (i.e. large) applications, is that when they fail, you can't just check the code and rerun the app on your machine. You have to read the (often massive) logs file, and hope you notice something that is out of place.

To make this work easier, you use hierarchies of severety for your log messages. You start from the most severe error, then work backwards, looking at progressively more granular messages, until some message shows you what went wrong.

The *implementation* for different logging functions may be practically the same, in that the messages end up in the same output. However, this doesn't make them "the same". The severety of the error is important. If your messages are annotated appropriately, you will be able to search through the logs, skipping the noise.

Here's a possible interpretation of the levels in `console`

| Level | Use |
| --- | --- |
| Degug | Low level info that is only relevant during development |
| Info | Details about what the program is doing |
| Log | High-level tracking about the state of the program |
| Warn | Something is wrong; nothing has failed yet |
| Error | The process didn't do what it was supposed to |
| Assert | The fundamental assumptions of the program have been broken. Anything after this can be garbage |