# Why is console.log() showing react_devtools_backend.js:4049 instead of the file and line number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, react-devtools

When I `console.log()`, the Chrome console gives the log but instead of showing the file and line number it just says `react_devtools_backend.js:4049`. How do I get the console to show the file and line number when I `console.log()`?

[image: screenshot of console output showing "react_devtools_backend.js:4049" in place of a correct file and line number]

Comment: Check the second answer to this question. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I was able to fix it in my console by adding the file to my Framework Ignore List in Chrome.
Steps:

> Console -> Gear icon (top right) -> Settings -> Framework Ignore List.

Add `react_devtools_backend.js` to the list and the `console.log` should start showing the correct mapping again.

[image: screenshot of Framework Ignore List in Chrome Settings]

Comment: Not sure if that's the best solution cause m.b. it will be needed in future? But at least it is working, thanks.

Comment: So what are you saying is that my page does not render for the second time?

Comment: I don't know why but doesn't work for me

Answer (score 54):

It can be disabled in "Components tab". Click the "Gear" icon:

[image: 1]

Then check "Hide logs during second render in Strict Mode" in the "Debugging" tab:

[image: 2]

Comment: This is the way

Comment: This doesn't seems to do anything in Firefox.

Comment: worked for me! Used chrome and react

Comment: Disabling "show inline warnings and errors" works for me in Firefox. Would be helpful if this answer actually specifically mentions the relevant option and how to set it. right now it's not really a direct answer to the question.

Answer (score 36):

Disable the React Devtools extension in your browser.

It looks like that extension needs a fix.

Answer (score 36):

To add a bit more context apparently "it doesn't need a fix" as it's working as intended as per version 18 of 1st of September 2021. See [comment of one of the developers](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/22257#issuecomment-915250655) on the React GitHub issue.

Quoting here in case you don't want to check the log or it gets deleted:

> As of the version 18 release, DevTools always overrides the native console to either dim or suppress StrictMode double logging. (Before it only did it if you enabled a feature like component stacks.)
>
> The major unfortunate drawback of this overriding is that it changes the location shown by the browser's console as reported in this issue.

So I guess that until they change their minds or browsers provide better support, it's time to switch off the extension.

Comment: My goodness, it's not really workable, having to enable and disable the extension constantly... Thanks for the info mate! Welcome to Stack :)

Answer (score 21):

We can use

```js
console.info(data)
```

instead of

```js
console.log(data)
```

Comment: The problem if when an error occurs and the code "breaks", so the developer wants to catch and debug, and if the extension is catching the error before the "real" code does, then the ability to know the exact line of failure is lost

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem since yesterday in both Edge & Chrome, not exactly a solution just a temporary workaround: just disable the react-devtools  extension from your browsers extensions.

Answer (score 3):

Render your App without the [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html):

```js
root.render(<App />)
```

Instead of:

```js
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

Comment: Never! Strict mode is life.

Answer (score 2):

This may be due to the source map option disabled in webpack config file. You need to change your devtool in webpack config as

```
devtool: "source-map"
```

or you can control source map generation according to your need. check the documentation of [devtool webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/)

Comment: Problematic when using `react-scripts` which handles all the *Webpack* for you as a "black-box"

Answer (score 1):

As of React DevTools version 19 of 29 September 2021, this issue has been addressed, as per the [comment on the GitHub issue page](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/22257#issuecomment-931353936).
So it should show the file and line number again after we update the React DevTools extension to version `4.19.0`.

Comment: I'm on version `4.22.0` and the line number is not visible in the log

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you are using React devtools extension in chrome. simply just go to chrome://extensions/ and check, If found then remove it. In my case it worked.

Comment: So for react developers you are suggesting removing react dev tools?