# why Console logs are generated from instrument.ts file in sentry.io

Tags: reactjs, sentry

Behaviour after integration sentry.io in react app.

1. Console logs are generated from the instremnts.ts file.
2. I have tried printing it from index page as well.

Answer (score 5):

Do you need it for production or development? We are using this integration to transform console logs into event breadcrumbs. If you don't need them in development (or at all), you can turn them off:

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: '_YOUR_DSN_',
  integrations: [new Sentry.Integrations.Breadcrumbs({ console: false })]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem with the suggestion that you can find here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69153985/9648137

He suggests adding the `react_devtools_backend.js` to the ignore list in the chrome settings, just add the `instrument.ts` similarly.