# nodejs console.log not writing before error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I read this: [is node.js' console.log asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127532/is-node-js-console-log-asynchronous) which says that stdout *used to* be asynchronous. However, I'm still seeing this problem in some specific cases like this:

```
console.log("first");
console.log("second");
throw "bah";
```

I had a lot of difficulty boiling down my application into this example. The issue here is that "first" prints, but "second" does not. Wth? Has anyone seen this type of problem before?

The version of node i'm using is: node-v0.10.3-x64

Comment: They both print out for me on v0.10.0-x64. Weird though. Maybe stdout isn't being fully flushed beforehand? What if you just throw an exception yourself?

Comment: Pure exception exhibits the problem too - edited the question to make that clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in node.js specific to windows. This is the likely bug:

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3584