# Console warning not displayed when performing exit in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, exit

I am new to Node.js. I have implemented an `\exit` link on my site. When it is browsed, the following function is called:

```
function exitRequest(req, res) {

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');    
    res.send("<html><body>Bye</body></html>");

    console.warn('%s: Exit requested.', Date(Date.now()) );
    process.exit(0);

};
```

The page is displayed properly and the `node.js` server shuts down, but the console warning is not displayed. However, calls to `console.warn` are successful in other parts of the application. I can see the messages in the output window.

What could cause this issue?

Comment: I believe console.log calls are asynchronous. If you exit the process it might be that they don't get to be executed. Hum...this link says is synch but has some good information on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127532/is-node-js-console-log-asynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to delay the process termination:

```
console.warn('%s: Exit requested.', Date(Date.now()));
process.nextTick(function() { process.exit(0); });
```

Or using `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function() { process.exit(0); }, 0);
```

If you don't want to create a new anonymous function, you could use bind:

```
var exit = process.exit.bind(process, 0);

// Later...
process.nextTick(exit);
```

Comment: setTimeout(function() { process.exit(0); }, 1000); worked, thanks!