# How to make console.log() behave synchronously in Phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, phantomjs

As far as I understand, phantomjs console is asynchronous. This means that this code will show a broken output:

```
console.log(very_long_text);
phantom.exit(0);
```

Only part of the `very_long_text` will be visible. The end of it will be lost, because of the asynchronous nature of `console.log()`.

What is the workaround? I need to see the entire `very_long_text`.

Maybe this discussion is relevant: [is node.js' console.log asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127532/is-node-js-console-log-asynchronous)

ps. This is the best I can do now, but it's extremely ugly:

```
console.log(very_long_text);
setTimeout(function() { phantom.exit(0); }, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that `console.log` run asynchronously ?

I can write 5MB to the console without any truncations.  You can try another overload by using system module like this example :

```
require('system').stdout.write(very_long_text);
phantom.exit(0);
```

So `console.log` is synchronous but may run inside an asynchronous code (eg a callback) . So you have to be very careful when using it, and especially where is located `phantom.exit`.

As you're using `console.log`, I suppose that *something* spawns a phantomjs instance. Some techs like Node.js, internally uses line/memory buffers : as a consequence, if your process ends suddenly (unhandled exception), it is entirely possible that the buffered output will never reach the screen  ; child process could also be killed if the amount of data allowed on stdout or stderr is exceeded (maxBuffer [here](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html))

At the end, If you want to write large contents, `console.log` may not be the best solution.