# Does `console.log` buffer output in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wonder if `console.log` buffers output in node.js or tries to perform IO on each invocation? This doesn't seem to be officially documented.

The question arose from the necessity to output an array of strings and I think which idiom is more efficient:

```
array.forEach(function(line){
  console.log(line)
})
```

or

```
console.log(array.join('\n'))
```

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to imagine the `forEach` method would be faster unless you already do it for something else, but the core question is interesting. +1

Comment: Well, in the second approach you allocate memory to the possibly big string up front, then send it all to `console.log`, which may or not have a buffer, using even more memory. In this case, the best option is to look at the source code

Comment: @Kroltan, looking at the sources is the best approach if you have enough time and expertise. But what if you don't?

Comment: Alex, sorry. The source for [console.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/console.js): Looking at the `log` function, it just prints the value + a newline. And the default behavior for that in the underlying C/C++ library is that it doesn't flush except when necessary, so yes, most of the time it buffers.

Comment: Very much related, if not duplicate: [is node.js' console.log asynchronous?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5127532/1048572) (and maybe [Difference between “process.stdout.write” and “console.log” in node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4976466/1048572))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for `console.log()` probably doesn't specify whether it buffers output because it [delegates that decision to an underlying stream](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.11.14/lib/console.js#L54-L56):

```
Console.prototype.log = function() {
  this._stdout.write(util.format.apply(this, arguments) + '\n');
};
```

The [`writable.write()`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_write_chunk_encoding_callback) it's using documents the general possibility of buffering:

> The return value indicates if you should continue writing right now. If the data had to be buffered internally, then it will return `false`. Otherwise, it will return `true`.
>
> This return value is strictly advisory. You MAY continue to write, even if it returns `false`. However, writes will be buffered in memory, so it is best not to do this excessively. Instead, wait for the `drain` event before writing more data.

Though, the global `console` uses [`process.stdout`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) that's more likely to block, buffering only under certain circumstances:

> `process.stderr` and `process.stdout` are unlike other streams in Node in that writes to them are usually blocking.
>
> - They are blocking in the case that they refer to regular files or TTY file descriptors.
> - In the case they refer to pipes:
>
>   - They are blocking in Linux/Unix.
>   - They are non-blocking like other streams in Windows.

To see whether any `line`s are buffered, you could `.write()` them to `stdout` yourself and capture the return value:

```
var util = require('util');
var buffered = [];

array.forEach(function(line){
  buffered.push(!process.stdout.write(util.format(line) + '\n'));
});

console.log(buffered);
```

Comment: Isn't the question then whether `this._stdout` *does* actually buffer?

Comment: @Bergi Sure, but it's not a simple "yes" or "no." It can buffer, but isn't guaranteed to.

Comment: Writables in general can be both, yes, but stdout is a very specific instance. And it's [known to be blocking](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout)