# Making requests with node.js in a loop performance

Tags: node.js, http, request

I'm trying to benchmark a Node.js express app with the following using the `request` library:

```
var request = require('request');

var totalRequests = 100000;

for(var i = 0; i < totalRequests; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        request('http://localhost:3000/', function(error, response, body) {
            console.info('Request ' + (i + 1));
        });
    })(i);
}
```

When I run it, I don't see the `console.info()` request callback for requests for over 40 seconds, then they start. Should'nt I see the requests firing right away?

Comment: Requests should be as fast as possible. Maybe there is a bad configuration or firewall issue with your localhost. Is port 3000 the correct port for you to be using? Print the response or response code. There may be a timeout issue.

Comment: If you're using callback it waits for the entire body to be loaded, which for that many requests made so suddenly might take that time. Maybe try using its stream api `.on('data')`

Comment: Even when I change the url to `http://google.com` there is still a delay.

Comment: The delay may be between the request finishing and the `.info()` appearing. [Some `console` methods are asynchronous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127532/is-node-js-console-log-asynchronous).

Answer (score 0):

40 seconds may be the amount of time it takes to prepare 100,000 requests. Since you're looping synchronously, your callbacks can't get called until after all of the requests have been initiated.

I suggest a library like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) if you intended to make some or all of the requests in series rather than in parallel.