# How do I delay this code running in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, timing

I have written this code to change an image:

```
change = function(){
    for (r=0; r<6; r++){
        for (i = 0; i < 6 ; i++) { 
            setInterval(imgfile(number=i+1), 5000);
        }
    }
}

imgfile= function(number){
    a = 'document.getElementById("imgdiv").src = "images/'+number+'.svg"';
    eval(a);
}
```

The function `change()` is called when a button is clicked.
When I press the button the image changes straight to 6.svg, when I want it to go through the images 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and to repeat it 6 times. When I change `setInterval` to `change.setInterval` or `imgfile.setInterval` it doesn't work at all. How do I fix this?

Comment: Why `eval()` ? O.o

Comment: The one rule of `eval`: don't use eval, because eval is evil.

Comment: You need to block scope your `i` variable with the `let` keyword or wrap it in a closure!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a delay in a JavaScript loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583724/how-do-i-add-a-delay-in-a-javascript-loop)

Comment: @MattWebb This change alone isn't enough so the code makes what it is supposed to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
change = function(i=0){
        imgfile(i%6+1);//change image
         if(i<36) setTimeout(change,5000,i+1);//next image in 5 seconds
}

imgfile= function(number){
    document.getElementById("imgdiv").src = "images/"+number+".svg";//no need to use ev(i||a)l
}
```

Instead of loop/interval mess you can simply start a timeout that restarts itself after changing the image... This code will loop over 6 images with a delay of 5 seconds and that 6 times...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
var index, imgCount, loopCount, imgTag, countdown;

index = 0;
imgCount = 6;
loopCount = 6;
imgTag = document.getElementById('imgdiv');

countdown = function () {
  if (index < imgCount * loopCount) {
    imgTag.src = 'images/' + index % imgCount + '.svg';
    index = index + 1;
    setTimeout(countdown, 5000);
  }
};

countdown();
```

Here we're avoiding the double loop and using modular math (index % imgCount) to get the right file number.

Answer (score 0):

For another question I wrote a nice utility function that has quite a number of uses, but can also handle this scenario very easily. The main issue is that there is no time elapsing between the different delays being set. So you are setting 6 different actions to all happen within 5000ms, and all will occur at the same moment.

Here's my [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41366438/how-to-output-to-console-in-real-time-in-javascript/41367497#41367497)

Here's the utility function for that answer, along with its application to your problem.

```js
function doHeavyTask(params) {
  var totalMillisAllotted = params.totalMillisAllotted;
  var totalTasks = params.totalTasks;
  var tasksPerTick = params.tasksPerTick;
  var tasksCompleted = 0;
  var totalTicks = Math.ceil(totalTasks / tasksPerTick);
  var initialDelay = params.initialDelay;
  var interval = null;
        
  if (totalTicks === 0) return;
  
  var doTick = function() {
    var totalByEndOfTick = Math.min(tasksCompleted + tasksPerTick, totalTasks);
  
    do {
      params.task(tasksCompleted++);
    } while(tasksCompleted < totalByEndOfTick);
     
    if (tasksCompleted >= totalTasks) clearInterval(interval);
  };
  
  // Tick once immediately, and then as many times as needed using setInterval
  if (!initialDelay) doTick();
  if (tasksCompleted < totalTicks) interval = setInterval(doTick, totalMillisAllotted / totalTicks);
}

// Do 6 actions over the course of 5000 x 6 milliseconds
doHeavyTask({
  totalMillisAllotted: 5000 * 6,
  totalTasks: 6,
  tasksPerTick: 1,
  initialDelay: false, // Controls if the 1st tick should occur immediately
  task: function(n) { console.log('Set image to "images/' + (n + 1) + '.svg"'); }
});
```

Comment: Its always a good idea to overhelm newbies with much code that does not belong to a solution... ;)

Answer (score -1):

You want to do `setTimeout()`.

`setTimeout` pauses for the millesecond value and then does the code. Where `setInterval` runs the code every whatever milleseconds.

Yeah, don't do `change.setInterval` or whatever, it is just `setInterval`.

An example for you would be this inside the for loop to replace the `setInterval` function.

```
setTimeout(imgfile(i+1), 5000);
```

Comment: please dont try to teach things to others that you dont quite understand yourself. setTimeout(imgfile(number=i+1), 5000); will call imgfile right **now**

Comment: Oh I understand, I just put the code he had. But yeah the parameter doesn't make that much sense.