# Difference between console.log and process._rawDebug

Tags: node.js

What is the difference between `console.log` and `process._rawDebug`?

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5127757/3398302) tells me that `console.log` actually calls `process.stdout.write` with formatting and a new line at the end. According to this [article](http://blog.trevnorris.com/2015/02/asyncwrap-tutorial-introduction.html) `process._rawDebug` also writes to the terminal but uses `process.stderr`. I'm not sure how reliable this article is, though.

I logged 10.000 messages (for testing purposes) to the console using `console.log` and `process._rawDebug`. The later was at least twice as fast which should mean something I guess.

Are there any dis(advantages) of using `console.log` or `process._rawDebug`? Which one is better/safer to use for logging small messages?

Answer (score 4):

I have found the answer on the Node 0.x archive repository on [Github](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/commit/906a175a0b40fc56dfafbe0929e4fbbb4df68ff2). The commit message description:

> This is useful when we need to push some debugging messages out to
>   stderr, without going through the Writable class, or triggering any kind
>   of nextTick or callback behavior.

The reason why it is faster is because it bypasses JavaScript entirely and the output is logged directly to the terminal.