# JavaScript: Console not logging without error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell

I made a simple function to illustrate my problem

I ran this code on Windows Powershell with Node.js, not on a browser. It doesn't log anything to the console. What am I doing wrong? I was just goofing around testing stuff. This is the only code in the file, nothing else.

```js
var sigma = function(nums) {
  var i = 0;
  var ops = nums.length - 1;
  var sum = 0;
  while (i <= ops) {
    sum += nums[i];
    i += 1;
  }
console.log(sum);
};
sigma([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Comment: How do you execute the code?

Comment: Possible answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49507426/295783

Comment: If I run node test.js (I named my file with your contents test.js) I get two logged lines "89" and "This also doesn't work". What I also found odd was that my node binaries weren't linked properly so I updated them with brew. I don't know if you also use mac, but if yes maybe you have a similar issue?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand what you mean by 'node binaries'. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install **node** in your environment ?

I means for javascript code you need to first compiled it.

Maybe after installing node environment , You need run it

***> node sigma.js***

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: _I ran this code on Windows Powershell with Node.js_

Comment: I have the environment installed.